# Python program on WordPress

Tags: python, wordpress, python-2.7

I'm trying to add some Python code to my WordPress site. They Python code creates a GUI using pygame. Is there anyway to put the program onto the WordPress site so users could interact with the GUI?

Comment: What is the result of the python code ? To be displayed in a website, the result must be something like HTML or images.

Comment: The Python code creates and interactive GUI